# How could we show the equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, monomorphisms

We have that $C$ is an algebraic closure of $F$ and $a,b\in C$.

We have the $F$-monomorphism $\tau: C\hookrightarrow C$ with $\tau (a)=b$.

From the mapping we have that $\tau (C)\subseteq C$.

Since $C$ is an algebraic closure of $F$, we have that $F\subseteq C$, and therefore $\tau (F)\subseteq \tau (C)$.

Since $\tau$ is a $F$-monomorphism, it holds that $\tau (F)=F$.

So, we have that $F\subseteq \tau (C)\subseteq C$.

How could we show that $\tau (C)=C$ ?

Comment: Can you prove that $\tau(C)$ is also an algebraic closure of $F$?  Then, by minimality, $C=\tau(C)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Prove that $\tau(C)$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.  Then, since $C$ cannot contain a proper subset that is also an algebraic closure, $\tau(C)$ must equal $C$.

Sketch: Suppose that $f\in F[x]$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$.  Let $c\in C$ be a root of $f$.  Since $f(c)=0$, apply $\tau$ to both sides to show that $f(\tau(c))=0$ so $\tau(C)$ also contains a root of $f$.

Comment: We have that $\tau (0)=0$ since $\tau$ is 1-1, right?

Comment: $\tau(0)=0$ since $0\in F$ and $\tau$ is an $F-$morphism.

Comment: Ah ok... To show that $\tau (C)$ is an algebraic closure we have to show that $\tau (C)$ is algebraic over $F$ and that $\tau(C)$ is algebraically closed. We have that $C$ is algebraically closed, so it contains a root for each non-constant polynomial in $F[x]$. For each root $c$, $\tau (c)\in \tau (C)$ is also a root. That means that $\tau (C)$ contains also a root for every polynomial in $F[x]$, so it is algebraically closed. We have that the extension $C/F$ is algebraic. Is $\tau (C)/F$ also algebraic?

Comment: Since $C$ is algebraic all of its elements are algebraic over $F$.  Since $\tau(C)$ is a subset of $C$, every element of $\tau(C)$ is algebraic over $F$.

Comment: When you write up your final version of this proof, I suggest that you write it about 3 times.  Go though each line of your proof and make sure that it is both necessary and correct.  Some of the sentences in what you wrote are somewhat confused, but if you analyze your answer, I think that you'll be able to clear up some of your confusions.

Comment: Perhaps you could type your proof as a new question and request feedback.

Comment: I thought about that again... Why can $C$ not contain a proper subset that is also an algebraic closure?

Comment: Algebraic closures are minimal.  It's the smallest field containing all roots.  If $C$ contained a proper subset which was algebraically closed, then it wouldn't be minimal.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you!! :-)